# Wpf how to capture framework control on keydown?

Tags: c#, wpf, frameworkelement

Currently my page works perfectly.

It has a button and a textbox as below:

```
<Button Command="{Binding [someViewModel].SomeCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding [someViewModel].userInput}"
```

And below I have the following definition for `SomeCommand`：

```
public ICommand SomeCommand {get;set;}

SomeCommand = RelayCommand<FrameworkElement>
    .GetInterceptableInstance((Action<FrameworkElement>)this.someMethod)
```

And below the definition for `someMethod`:

```
private void someMethod(FrameworkElement control)
{
     MessageBox.Show(this.userInput);
}
```

Basically, now when user click on the button, there will be a messagebox popping out and displaying the userInput. There are no problem and works perfectly.

Now I'm trying to invoke `someMethod` when user key in ENTER at `TextBox` but I've no idea what parameter I should provide to `someMethod`.

Below is my implementation of detecting enter key:

```
private void DetectEnterKey(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Key==Key.Return)
    {
        //this.someMethod() with what parameter?

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing a `FrameworkElement` into your method when it's not used at all? Can't you just pass the `string` text instead?

Comment: @Sheridan: I'm sorry to forget include the code. It will be used to create a new thread by `control.Dispatcher.Invoke`. My bad for trying to simplify the situation